# WInform DataGridView to Datetimepicker C#

Tags: winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker

I want to pass cell, which is date format in DataGridView to show in DateTimePicker.

How would I do that?
I set like below:
**DateTimePicker: modifydtpPurchase / dgvAssetList: DataGridView.

```
private void dgvAssetList_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        PCId modifyAsset = new PCId();
        modifyAsset.modifydtpPurchase.Value = this.dgvAssetList.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value;
        modifyAsset.modifytxtSpec.Text = this.dgvAssetList.CurrentRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
        modifyAsset.ShowDialog();
    }

modifyAsset.modifydtpPurchase.Value = this.dgvAssetList.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like below:

```
            modifyAsset.modifydtpPurchase.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dgvAssetList.CurrentRow.Cells[13].Value);
```